# Ruby (rails) Open Emails from Google Apps and get attached picture

Tags: ruby, gmail, google-apps

I have an email account in Google Apps that I use to get emails with one attached picture. I want to write a script that gets the emails from that account and get the attached picture of each email and later it upload it to a server.

My question is: What is the recommended way of doing this in Ruby? I assume it's using OAuth using IMAP. But, I am looking for libraries of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail before and it has worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail